# php preg_match_all html dates with slashes error

Tags: php

I've  trying to preg_match_all a date with slashes in it sitting between 2 html tags; however its returning null.

here is the html:

```
> <td width='40%' align='right'class='SmallDimmedText'>Last Login: 11/14/2009</td>
```

Here is my preg_match_all() code

```
preg_match_all('/<td width=\'40%\' align=\'right\' class=\'SmallDimmedText\'>Last([a-zA-Z0-9\s\.\-\',]*)<\/td>/', $h, $table_content, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

where $h is the html above.

what am i doing wrong?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It (from a quick glance) is because you are trying to match:

```
Last Login: 11/14/2009
```

With this regex:

```
Last([a-zA-Z0-9\s\.\-\',]*)
```

The regex doesn't contain the required characters of `:` and `/` which are included in the text string. Changing the required part of the regex to:

```
Last([a-zA-Z0-9\s\.\-\',:/]*)
```

Gives a match

Would it be better to simply use a [DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), and then preform the regex on the result of the DOM lookup? It makes for nicer regex...

**EDIT**

The other issue is that your HTML is:

...40%' align='right'class='SmallDimmedText'>...

Where there is no space between align='right' and class='SmallDimmedText'

However your regex for that section is:

...40%\' align=\'right\' class=\'SmallDimmedText\'>...

Where it is indicated there is a space.

**Use a DOM Parser** It will save you more headaches caused by subtle bugs than you can count.

Just to give you an idea on how simple it is to parse using Simple HTML DOM.

```
$html = str_get_html(...);
$elems = $html->find('.SmallDimmedText');
if ( count($elems->children()) != 1 ){
    throw new Exception('Too many/few elements found');
}
$text = $elems->children(0)->plaintext;

//parsing here is only an example, but you have removed all
//the html so that any regex used is really simple.
$date = substr($text, strlen('Last Login: '));
$unixTime = strtotime($date);
```

Answer (score 1):

I see at least two problems :

- in your HTML string, there is no space between `'right'` and `class=`, and there is one space there in your regex
- you must add at least these 3 characters to the list of matched characters, between the `[]` :

  - '`:`' *(there is one between "Login" and the date)*,
  - ' ' *(there are spaces between "Last" and "Login", and between ":" and the date)*,
  - and '`/`' *(between the date parts)*

With this code, it seems to work better :

```
$h = "<td width='40%' align='right'class='SmallDimmedText'>Last Login: 11/14/2009</td>";
if (preg_match_all("#<td width='40%' align='right'class='SmallDimmedText'>Last([a-zA-Z0-9\s\.\-',: /]*)<\/td>#", 
        $h, $table_content, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)) {
    var_dump($table_content);
}
```

I get this output :

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string '<td width='40%' align='right'class='SmallDimmedText'>Last Login: 11/14/2009</td>' (length=80)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string ' Login: 11/14/2009' (length=18)
```

Note I have also used :

- `#` as a regex delimiter, to avoid having to escape slashes
- `"` as a string delimiter, to avoid having to escape single quotes

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be to minimize the amount of text you have in the preg_match_all, why not just do between a ">" and a "<"? Second, I'd end up writing the regex like this, not sure if it helps:

```
/>.*[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4}</
```

That will look for the end of one tag, then any character, then a date, then the beginning of another tag.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Yacoby.

At the very least, remove all reference to any of the HTML specific and simply make the regex

```
preg_match_all('#Last Login: ([\d+/?]+)#', ...
```